# How to logout from stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

How to logout from stackexchange.com?

My question is straightforward, but I thought I'd format my question properly to meet question quality standards.
I made reasonable searches but I found nowhere how to logout without clearing cache manually.

Any tips?

Comment: You can check out but you can never leave

Answer (score 8):

[image: click it]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this screenshot steps:

[image]

Hope it helps!